# Adding and retrieving a file at runtime in Docker

Tags: docker

I've created my own docker image which contains two nodejs applications. Both applications read from one file and then output a different file.

How do I input the source file and get the output file on my local file system?

Comment: Give serious consideration to just running the applications locally.  You won’t need special software setup (just Node), you won’t need administrator permission to run the program, and you won’t need weird filesystem remapping tricks.

Comment: You can bind the volume to the image and give its location in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mount a volume when running the container using the -v flag (more info [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume)). This will give the container access to a directory on your local system and all files written to the mapped volume will be persisted on your local volume.

`docker run -v /full/path/to/source:/path/inside/container imagename`